# Symfony serve looks for PHP libraries at the wrong place

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cli

I had previously multiple installations of PHP on my computer. I deleted all of them and reinstalled php from the official source which is now found at `C:\\php`.

The symfony serve command (ran from PhpStorm console) looks for missing modules in the wrong directory. (I don't even have xampp anymore, but even if I copy the files to the location it tries, it doesn't work) Xampp folder is not in my Path env variable either.

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ftp.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ftp.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_ftp.dll.
dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Have you checked php.ini file?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First problem turns out to be that PhpStorm does not see my PHP installations on C: for some kind of weird permission error. (PATH was correct).

The compiled Windows version of PHP downloaded from php.net defaults the extension folder to `C:/php`, which had to be overriden using `php.ini`'s `extension_dir="D:/php/ext"` directive.

Answer (score 1):

run `symfony local:php:refresh` to fetch available PHP version of your systems.
`local:php:list` for list locally available PHP versions

Comment: I did `symfony local:php:list` but it doesn't show all the php versions on my system, only the ones of wamp64 and xampp whereas I have other versions in `C:/php/` . I also did the refresh command but it doesn't fix it. Any idea ?